# How to syncdb in django 1.7

Tags: python-2.7, django-models

**Directory structure**

`MyDjangoWebsite

               |MyDjangoWebsite

               |manage.py

               |MyBlog

                      |models.py

                      |__init__.py

                      |views.py

                      |migrations`

`MyBlog` is the app I created using `startapp` command. I have added a class in `MyBlog/models.py`.

When I run `python manage.py syncdb` or `python manage.py migrate`, I get `No migrations to apply`.

I am using `django 1.7`. Please let me know how can I add my tables to database.

Answer (score 1):

The steps to follow are:

1. Make changes in models
2. Run `manage.py makemigrations` - this is what generates the migrations file, which lists the changes that need to be applied (the migrations).
3. Run `manage.py migrate` - this will apply the migrations created by `makemigrations`.

If you skip step #2, then there are no migration (nothing to "migrate") so that's why you get that message.

As 1.7 was released, the tutorial was also updated and now includes [a section on migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/) which I would recommend going over.

Comment: I am getting this message for step 2. `No changes detected`

Comment: Please go through the (updated) [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/).